# Replacing JSON obj with letters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, replace

The output of this code will be the `name` and the `choices`
I want to replace the `Not effective`, `Neither effective nor Effective`, `Effective` with "A", "B", and "C". Respectively.

I don't know what is wrong or missing with my code, seems like it just works when I choose `Not effective` for Question 1, `Neither effective nor Effective` for Question 2, and `Effective` for Question 3.
This output I chose `Not effective` for all of the questions: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90zwv.png)

```
   Survey
        .StylesManager
        .applyTheme("defaultV2");
    
        const json = {
            pages: [
              {
                questions: [
                  {
                    type: "radiogroup",
                    name: "Question 1",
                    title: "Deliver through others.",
                    choices: [
                      "Not effective",
                      "Neither effective nor Effective",
                      "Effective"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    type: "radiogroup",
                    name: "Question 2",
                    title: "Understand others perspective.",
                    choices: [
                      "Not effective",
                      "Neither effective nor Effective",
                      "Effective"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    type: "radiogroup",
                    name: "Question 3",
                    title: "Solve complex problems.",
                    choices: [
                      "Not effective", 
                      "Neither effective nor Effective",
                      "Effective"
                    ]
                  },
                ]
              }
            ]
          };
    
    window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);
    
    survey
        .onComplete
        .add(function (sender) {
            let data = JSON.stringify(sender.data)
            data = data.replace("Not effective", "A")
            data = data.replace("Neither effective nor Effective", "B")
            data = data.replace("Effective", "C")
    
            var obj = JSON.parse(data)
    
            document
                .querySelector('#surveyResult')
                .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3);
    
        });
    
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#surveyElement',
        data: {
            survey: survey
        }
    });
```

Comment: you could use `data.replaceAll` ... but why not make the changes BEFORE you `JSON.stringify(sender.data)` ... then it's real easy

Comment: @LuckyLlemos I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output, I think you are looking for `replaceAll` instead of `replace`.

You can have a look at it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Answer (score 0):

*.replace() returns a new string (it does not modify the existing string)*

So you would need to replace and assign back into the choices array. For Ex. **:**

```
choices[0] = choices[0].replace("Not effective", "A");
choices[1] = choices[1].replace("Neither effective nor Effective", "B");
choices[2] = choices[2].replace("Effective", "C");
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
const json = {
  pages: [
    {
      questions: [
        {
          type: "radiogroup",
          name: "Question 1",
          title: "Deliver through others.",
          choices: [
            "Not effective",
            "Neither effective nor Effective",
            "Effective"
          ]
        },
        {
          type: "radiogroup",
          name: "Question 2",
          title: "Understand others perspective.",
          choices: [
            "Not effective",
            "Neither effective nor Effective",
            "Effective"
          ]
        },
        {
          type: "radiogroup",
          name: "Question 3",
          title: "Solve complex problems.",
          choices: [
            "Not effective", 
            "Neither effective nor Effective",
            "Effective"
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    questions: json.pages[0].questions,
    updatedData: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updatedData = this.questions.map((obj) => {
        obj.choices[0] = obj.choices[0].replace("Not effective", "A");
      obj.choices[1] = obj.choices[1].replace("Neither effective nor Effective", "B");
      obj.choices[2] = obj.choices[2].replace("Effective", "C");
      return obj;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(question, index) in updatedData" :key="index">
    <p v-for="choice in question.choices" :key="choice">
      {{ choice}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

FYI **:** In JavaScript, strings are immutable - an existing string is never modified.